# iOS - Xcode module build similar to Android

Tags: ios, xcode, build, module

Android Studio provides module build facility, where different module can be built on its own inside same project. Is there anything similar in Xcode?

Little guide with explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: why? what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a big project with some modules. Modules are required to build and test individually. To reduce build time i want to use module build if possible. @Wain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a workspace which can hold multiple projects. You can build each separate project separately and include the required different projects in your final build project. You can run different test codes for different projects also with this approach.

Comment: Can you explain how can i make  different modules under same application and interlink them togethe.